# How to open a UIDocument after UIDocumentStateSavingError exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument, nsmetadataquery

In my iCloud-based app, I noticed that if a crash were to occur while a UIDocument is open (and has not yet been closed), the status of the document sometimes becomes `UIDocumentStateSavingError` and it never opens successfully again.

When I run `[UIDocument openWithCompletionHandler:]` after this, the document never opens, returning `NO` for `success` and 5 (`UIDocumentStateClosed` and `UIDocumentStateSavingError`) for `documentState`.

On iOS 5, I also observed that `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` is constantly being called (every second) until the file is deleted and the app is restarted. This causes additional usability problems in the app.

One more thing, on developer.icloud.com I noticed that the file is showing a second, conflicted version existing. This conflict isn't found on any of my devices, though, not even if the app is restarted or reinstalled.

**What do I do to get the UIDocument to open normally?**

Here is what I tried so far:

- Checking `[NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:]` for conflicts and removing all older version using `[NSFileVersion removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:]`.
- Calling `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:]` before calling `[UIDocument openWithCompletionHandler:]` to re-download the file to the device.
- Downloading the main and conflicted versions from developer.icloud.com to see if any of them are corrupt or partial files. Both open fine.
- Banging my head against my desk. Preliminary results are unsuccessful.

Comment: I've fixed similar issues using the "evictUbiquitousItemAtURL".   Are you checking for success or is it throwing an error?

Comment: Both: `evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:` returns `YES` and does not produce an error for me.

Comment: Are you using a metaquery to get the document name?  Sometimes when a save fails it leaves a partial file and that's one of the files returned by the query

Comment: Yes, I am. If it's a partial file, would `evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:` not get rid of it and re-download, though?

Comment: I don't think it does. When I ran into a similar problem, I solved it using the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338371/warning-in-icloud-integration

Comment: btw, the evict just gets rid of the local copy, so it would just download the same broken file again I think.

Comment: Wait... so you're saying that the crash could permanently corrupt the file?

Comment: Also, I have 6 test devices, and every time I have this problem it correctly opens on a few of them and not others. This must mean the file is isn't corrupted somewhere. As I mentioned, on developer.icloud.com it shows a conflict that none of the devices pick up.

Comment: I would guess that the devices that work have a local copy that is fine - the broken copy is probably the "latest" and every other device that syncs after that gets the "bad" file.  This is speculation, but is based on what I've seen.

Comment: I think a crash doesn't "permanently" corrupt the file as much as it loses the last changes.

Comment: I see what you mean, though one of the tests I did involved letting changes sync for a while, and everything synced--but the "bad" files didn't.

Comment: I also found that copying the "bad" file locally and opening the copy works (this is done programmatically as a test, iCloud is not turned off).